# Sublime Text 2 - Adjust indenting template

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way of changing the default indent template for autocompletions in Sublime Text 2? For example if I have:

```
div {}
```

and hit enter between the parentheses, I get:

```
div {

}
```

but what I'd like to get is:

```
div {

    }
```

It's just a personal taste thing, but I'm wondering if it's achievable via one of the config files. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just added a tab into the line - like so:


    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n\n\t"} },

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its some sort of a bug.

In javascript files (at least when i write nodeJs stuff) it messes up indentation.

Try selecting everything and select "reindent".

Looking forward to Sublime 3